# Asymptotic Estimates for recurrence

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

Let  $$y_{n+1}-y_n\thicksim (1-y_{n+1})^k$$ where $y_n\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$.
I was able to show that for $k>1$, $$y_n-1\thicksim \frac{1}{n^\frac{1}{k-1}}.$$

What will the asymptotic estimate for $0<k<1$ be please? It seems to me it will be $$y_n-1\thicksim k^{-n}$$ but I cannot show it.

REMARK: $x_n\thicksim y_n$ if $\frac{x_n}{y_n}\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Surely this $\sim$ only makes sense if you specify some limit for $n$, eg $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Yes as $n\mapsto \infty$

Comment: Have to tried to approximate $y_{n+1}-y_n \approx y'(n), \,\, y_{n+1} \approx y(n) $ this oftenly works pretty well to get first asymptotic order of difference equations

Comment: @asgeige Yes, i did. It worked for $k>1$ but not in the case of interest $0<k<1$.

Answer (score 2):

**new answer** replacing the old non-answer.

Here is an example in the case $k=1/2$.  Let $a$ be a fixed number $0<a<1$.  Then consider
$$
y_n = 1-a^{2^n}
$$
so that $y_n \to 1^-$.
Now we have
$$
\sqrt{1-y_{n+1}} = \sqrt{a^{2^{n+1}}} = a^{2^n}
$$
and as $n \to \infty$
$$
y_{n+1}-y_n = a^{2^n} - a^{2^{n+1}} =
a^{2^n}\left(1-a^{2^n}\right) \sim a^{2^n}
$$
and thus
$$
y_{n+1} - y_n \sim \big(1-y_{n+1}\big)^{1/2}
$$
But of course
$a^{2^n}$ is not asymptotic to $(1/2)^{-n} = 2^n$ as conjectured, nor is it asymptotic to $(1/2)^n = 2^{-n}$ as was perhaps the intended conjecture.  In this example, $y_n$ converges to $1$ much faster than either of those conjectures.

Comment: I believe the OP's claim is that for fixed $k>1$, $$
y_n  \sim 1 + n^{\frac{1}{{1 - k}}} ,
$$ and for the case $0<k<1$, their guess is $$
y_n  \sim 1 + k^{ - n} 
$$ and asks for a possible proof of this.

Comment: @Gary Yes, that is exactly the question.